# Django admin page not found at /admin/

Tags: django, admin

I just install apache and django.

The django default page works fine:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

but the /admin/ site not:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /admin/ was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at 69.162.92.53 Port 80

Apache conf (/etc/init.d/apache2/sites-avaliable/mysite.conf) file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

ServerName mysite.com.br
Alias /static /var/www/mysite/media/static/

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi file (/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py):

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/mysite')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Django mysite.settings (/var/www/mysite/mysite/settings.py):

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
...
```

Django mysite.urls (/var/www/mysite/mysite/urls.py):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

That's all. am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the apache error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an apache configuration error.

I believe you should be pointing at:-

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I had to make this change and in httpd.conf file (/var/apache2/httpd.conf) I had write the following line: include /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf. Now works fine.  sry for my english.

Comment: Explicitly adding an Include like that is wrong. You are meant to symlink the file into the sites-enabled directory. There is even a admin script on most Linux distros to do it for you. On Ubuntu you would have run 'sudo a2ensite mysite'.

Comment: Yes, @GrahamDumpleton is right. Since you are using debian or ubuntu, you should use `sudo a2ensite mysite`.

Comment: I did use 'a2ensite mysite.conf' and doenst work. the only way it works is by adding that 'include' in 'httpd.conf'. (I'm usin the 'a2ensite' and that 'include' together to make this work).